# Linq In Parallel.ForEach

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, parallel.foreach

I have a foreach loop with Linq queries inside.

Everything runs great until I change the foreach to Parallel.ForEach:

```
// get the task info   ---------
                Log("Populate task, guf code lists ...........................");
                List<SF_CO_ITEM> tasks = (from coi in ctx.SF_CO_ITEM
                                                    where coi.CO == co.ID
                                                    select coi).ToList();

               // foreach (SF_CO_ITEM t in tasks)
               // {
                Parallel.ForEach(tasks, t =>
                {
                    Log("Executing on t: " + t.ID);

                    // exception on next line:
                    List<SF_CO_LINE_ITEM> gufs = (from coli in ctx.SF_CO_LINE_ITEM      
                                                            where coli.CO_ITEM == t.ID
                                                            select coli).ToList();
```

And the exception I get is:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled   Message=Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.   Source=Oracle.DataAccess   StackTrace:
>          at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsCon.Open(IntPtr& opsConCtx, IntPtr& opsErrCtx, OpoConValCtx* pOpoConValCtx, OpoConRefCtx&
>   pOpoConRefCtx)
>          at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionDispenser.Open(OpoConCtx opoConCtx)
>          at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at ChangeOrder.Program.<>c_*DisplayClass19.b*_16(SF_CHANGE_ORDER_ITEM
>   t) in C:\VS_apps\PMConsole\PMC
>   Tools\ChangeOrderExecution\Program.cs:line 220
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c_*DisplayClass2d`2.<ForEachWorker>b__23(Int32
>   i)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b*_c()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6(Object
>   )
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteSelfReplicating(Task root)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task
>   task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued, Object threadStatics)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously(TaskScheduler
>   scheduler)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler scheduler)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
>   Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1
>   localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1
>   list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body)
>          at ChangeOrder.Program.PerformChangeOrder(SF_CHANGE_ORDER co, SF_CLIENT_PROJECT cp, SFEntitiesQA ctx) in C:\VS_apps\PMConsole\PMC
>   Tools\ChangeOrderExecution\Program.cs:line 216
>          at ChangeOrder.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\VS_apps\PMConsole\PMC Tools\ChangeOrderExecution\Program.cs:line
>   1373
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

I'm not sure what I would need to lock since I am just grabbing information (just RO, right?).

I've thought about adding the "AsParallel" but my understanding is that's a PLINQ directive that just causes the query to run in parallel with respect to itself.

I can't find any examples of people running Linq queries inside Parallel.ForEach loops, so I'm not even sure what I'm doing is allowed.

Comment: Well changing a `foreach` to `Parallel.ForEach` is a *major* change. You need to make sure that the operation can actually run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do the join itself instead of getting each one individually? Since it looks like this is hitting a DB, your LINQ provider should just compose the query and get you the rows you're looking for. Try this:

```
List<SF_CO_LINE_ITEM> gufs;
var query = from coi in ctx.SF_CO_ITEM
            where coi.CO == co.ID
            join coli in ctx.SF_CO_LINE_ITEM      
                on coi.ID == coli.CO_ITEM
            select coli;
// Confirm what the query looks like by calling 'query.ToString()'
gufs = query.ToList();
```

I'll usually separate the query from the actual enumeration/materialization, that way I can validate that the query looks like I want. If this is a 1:M relationship between `SF_CO_ITEM` and `SF_CO_LINE_ITEM`, then you should do a GroupJoin by changing the join to:

```
join coli in ctx.SF_CO_LINE_ITEM      
    on coi.ID == coli.CO_ITEM into tcoli
from tc in tcoli
select tc
```

As for why you're getting this exception, might have something to do with trying to access the context from a different thread. As per [MSDN article on Parallel loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx):

> Hidden Loop Body Dependencies
>
> Incorrect analysis of loop dependencies is a frequent source of software 
>       defects. Be careful that all parallel loop bodies do not contain hidden 
>       dependencies. This is a mistake that's easy to make.
>
> The case of trying to share an instance of a class such as Random or 
>       DbConnection, which are not thread safe, across parallel iterations is 
>       an example of a subtle dependency.

So your only options are to keep it sequential instead of parallel or to alter the original query to a join so that you get the right data the first time around.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Svick. I *could* combine the 2 queries, but what I left out was there are a lot of queries in that foreach block that need the one object but not the other. I can't really break up the contexts because I need everything to happen in 1 transaction. So it looks like the only feasible option I have is to keep it serial.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a thread-safe database context class ... probably a nice amount of money to be made there.